# JavaScript defining an array size and cloning from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my following code:

```
customQuestionnaire['questions'] = customQuestionnaire['questions'].slice(0,numberOfQuestions);
```

I want to output an array size of numberOfQuestions and yet copying up to the array of numberOfQuestions over. This works if the array previously was larger. But what if the array previously was smaller and I want to declare a larger array (the rest being 'undefined')? Should I do this instead? Or the above code suffice.

```
var temp = customQuestionnaire['questions'].slice(0,numberOfQuestions);
customQuestionnaire['questions'] = new Array(numberOfQuestions);
customQuestionnaire['questions'] = temp.slice();
```

But this looks the same as the previous code. How should I go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to fill the rest of the array until the desired length with undefined values. For example:

```
var numberOfQuestions  = 10;
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var result = arr.slice(0,numberOfQuestions);

if(numberOfQuestions > arr.length){
    var interations = numberOfQuestions - arr.length;
   for(var i =0; i< interations; i++){
        result.push(undefined);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

for this example the output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

So you have a new array with length of numberOfQuestions. Existing values are copied and if you try to use values which are undefined you will get erro

Answer (score 0):

The code that uses a `temp` var won't do anything different from your original code.

```
// This creates a copy of the array stored in customQuestionnaire['questions']
// and stores it in temp
var temp = customQuestionnaire['questions'].slice(0,numberOfQuestions);

// this creates a new empty array with a length of numberOfQuestions and
// stores it in customQuestionnaire['questions']
customQuestionnaire['questions'] = new Array(numberOfQuestions);

// this creates a copy of the array stored in temp (itself a copy) and
// immediately overwrites the array created in the last step with this copy of
// the array we created in the first step.
customQuestionnaire['questions'] = temp.slice();
```

Using `.slice` creates a copy of the array you are calling the method on, but since you are immediately overwriting the array, I'm assuming you don't need to preserve the original value of `customQuestionnaire['questions']`.

The easiest (and likely most efficient) way to accomplish what you want is to simply adjust the [`.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of the array.

```
customQuestionnaire['questions'].length = numberOfQuestions;
```

If `numberOfQuestions` is shorter than the length of the array this will truncate the array to `numberOfQuestions` questions. If `numberOfQuestions` is longer than the array the array will mutate into an array that contains `numberOfQuestions` items, the items beyond the original array's length will be `undefined` as you desired.

If you do need to copy the original array, you could still use `.slice` to do that:

```
var questionnaire = customQuestionnaire['questions'].slice();
questionnaire.length = numberOfQuestions;
// do something with questionnaire
```